# How draw vertical line while hovering tooltip (with vue-chartjs)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

I'm using vue-chartjs in my nuxt.js project. I have line chart and I want to draw vertical line while hovering like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pundoo/haq5k2mw/). Below chart options.
The problem is that I could not integrate code from the example with vue. Thanks in advance))

**WeatherChart.vue**

```html
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: false,
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
          mode: 'x',
          intersect: false,
          xPadding: 14,
          yPadding: 14,
          position: 'nearest',
          custom: (tooltipModel) => {
            // Tooltip Element
            let tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip')
            //There some options
          },
        },
      },
    }
  },
  mounted() {  
    
    this.renderChart(
      {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Kunduzi',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 195, 137, 1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 195, 137, 1)',
            borderWidth: 3,
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 195, 137, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 255, 246, 0.5)',
            data: this.dataDay,
            fill: '+1',
          },
          {
            label: 'Kechasi',
            borderColor: 'rgba(19, 133, 250, 1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(19, 133, 250, 1)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(19, 133, 250, 1)',
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(212, 234, 255, 0.5)',
            data: this.dataNight,
          },
        ],
      },
      this.options
    )
  },

}
</script>
```